# SQLWatch Report "contains no data"

Tags: report

We have SQLWatch 2.6.

I have a check query that is generating an email.

The email should contain the output of a report however in the email body i see:

Report Id: 56 contains no data.

I run the query in the report in SSMS and it produces results.

Every thing is connected properly in the following tables but I can't figure out why my report is producing no data:
Table                   Entries
sqlwatch_config_action          2
sqlwatch_config_check           1
sqlwatch_config_check_action        1
sqlwatch_config_check_action_template   1
sqlwatch_config_report          1
sqlwatch_config_report_action       1